# What is the fastest way to count user logins in a sessions table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

my objective is to efficiently count the number of logins for each user across combinations of dates. It is worth mentioning that:

1. Margin of error is accepted *(let's say up to 3% for the sake of the example).*
2. The count is non-distinct (if a user logged in more than once, I want to know the number of times)

I have created a simplified example to illustrate my point better.

Let's say we have a large sessions table that only contains a `user_id` and a `timestamp` that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (
    user_id text,
    tstamp  timestamp
)
```

Now let's say that we want to count the number of sessions that each user had (if a `user_id` is present on a time, we know that means a log-in) on both the granularity of a day and month. This can be illustrated by this query (which I want to optimize):

```
    SELECT user_id,
           date_trunc('day', tstamp)::date   AS cohort_day,
           date_trunc('month', tstamp)::date AS cohort_month,
           count(*)                          AS number_of_sessions
    FROM sessions
    GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

The result table should look something like:

```
user_id    cohort_date cohort_month  number_of_sessions 
123456789  2020-06-25  2020-06-01    3                  
622428294  2020-06-22  2020-06-01    2                  
222678293  2020-06-23  2020-06-01    9                  
422288297  2020-06-24  2020-06-01    1
```

Lastly, this table is part of the ETL (Postgres) and the tables are drop and rebuilt on every run.

Comment: That `GROUP BY 1,2,3` clause is the frowned-upon way to write `GROUP BY user_id,  date_trunc('day', tstamp)::date,  date_trunc('month', tstamp)::date`.It's slow because it forces a full table scan to calculate the day and month values before grouping them, that can't be accelerated by indexing.

Comment: Do you want fastest answers to ad hoc queries about random users for random time granularity?

Comment: How do you truncate 2020-06-25 to the month and get 2020-03-01?  I don't see how your given query can do what you want, at any speed.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes for making me notice this. I created random data so must have replaced a 06 with a 03. I have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a *materialized view* for your query that contains the already aggregated data. That is fast to query, and if you refresh the materialized view often enough, the data will be close enough to reality.

`count` itself [is never fast](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-count-made-fast/).

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. Materialized view could be a bit tricky as this table is part of the ETL and the tables are drop and rebuilt on every run. Is it possible to use hashing or some other technique to aggregate data faster?

Comment: If the tables are used more often than they are rebuilt, that should be simple: you just build the materialized view as part of the ETL process.

Comment: This is a “data warehouse” approach, which is the fastest approach. You may find nosql databases are faster than an RDBMS like Postgres (which performs very well), but they probably won’t be *that* much faster in absolute terms.