# Is updating a materialized view in Postgres an idempotent operation?

Tags: database, postgresql

After digging deeper into [potential speed-ups for queries that involve aggregations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62573301/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-count-user-logins-in-a-sessions-table?noredirect=1#comment110663062_62573301) I found that updating `Materialized Views` with:

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW foo.bar;
```

may offer a significant boost in querying aggregated data.

I have three related questions:

1. Is updating a Materialized View considered an [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) operation?
2. If so, how is it different from rebuilding the table or re-running the query?
3. Does refreshing a materialized view have a benefit to gain from caching?

Comment: Might be better asked on sister site http://DBA.StackExchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, if the underlying data didn't change in the mean time.
2. The query that defines the table is run when the materialized view is refreshed. So there is no difference here. But if you would need to run the same query often, and instead you query the materialized view, that is a performance gain.
3. Just like any query: if the underlying tables are cached, `REFRESH` will be faster.

Comment: Thanks again @Laurenz! So if I have a persistent table and a materialized view that both have the same aggregated data, does that mean I will have no performance benefit from querying one over the other?

Comment: Absolutely true. A materialized view is effectively a table.